# Input Validation Pseudocode for Emails?

Tags: validation, pseudocode

What would be some basic pseudocode to describe input validation for emails?
Something like:

```
Prompt user for email

Input == Email

...
```

Comment: Please include more specifics.  Like the language.  Or what you want to accomplish with validation ("looks like an email", actually is a registered email, etc.)

Comment: @ryanyuyu No language in particular, something close to general english language that looks code like lol

Comment: Again, what do you want to validate?  How do you want to define what makes an input a valid email?

Comment: @ryanyuyu a certain about of letters, numbers or -/_ then a @ symbol then a certain amount of letters then a . and 3 letters or 2 letters then a . then 2 more letters.

Comment: Look into regex (regular expressions).  They define rules to match a string.  See also this [javascript regex solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript).  According to your rules specifically, something like `^[\w-]+@[\w.%+-]+\.\w{2,3}\.[A-Za-z]{2}$` would work.